# Can NM cable be run tight to the underside of subfloor?

Tags: electrical

I recently had an electrician wire four LED recessed lights in my kitchen. 2 of the lights are under my upstairs bathroom tub (just under the copper and drain pipes). Is it code or acceptable for installation?

Also, when feeding cable to one of the other lights, the hole in the floor joist is just below the subflooring. Not sure if this will be a problem down the road? The subfloor itself does not appear to be damaged.

Location NY/US

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the cable at the sub floor blocked from above by the tub? I was not clear on that part.  running the romex with the pipes is fine for both metallic pipes and plastic types.

Answer (score 2):

That is such a baffling choice for drilling a hole. Was there something on the other side which prevented drilling in the center of the joist?

I believe you need a nail plate whenever a wire is within 1.25" of the edge of a stud/joist so a nail plate should probably be used.

Below is the notching guide for joists. As long as that notch is not in the middle third of the joist span then it should be fine from a structural standpoint.

Even if it is in the middle span of the joist, such a small notch is probably inconsequential so I wouldn't lose any sleep over it.

[image]

[Source](https://elizabethtown.wini.com/resources/tech-articles/improper-notching-and-boring-joists/)

Comment: I am guessing the tech drilled the hole using a flex auger which is why it is close to the sub floor. The ceiling wasn't cut out to after the fact (making this assumption as I wasn't watching). Just want to make sure the job was done correct or to code.

Comment: @RyanF I see, is that notch in the middle third span of the joist?

Comment: The length of the joist is 136'' and the notch is at 50'' from the edge. So from the above diagram it appears it is in the middle. I was more concerned of a staple going through (if carpet was ever replaced) then structural since little material was removed.

Comment: @RyanF I doubt the notch matters structurally but you are correct in your puncture concerns. Carpet staples, carpet tack strips, hardwood floors, random screws to fix squeaking, etc... are all a hazard. I would ask the electrician to re-drill and re-run the cable closer to the middle of the depth.